# Best practice for handling input check for void function

Tags: c, assert

This may be a huge noob question, but I am relatively new to C and to using 'assert'.

Say I'm building a large program and have a void function test() which takes in an array and performs some manipulation to the array.

Now, as I build this program, I'll want to make sure that all my inputs for my functions are valid, so I want to make sure the array passed into test() is valid (i.e. not null let's say).

I can write something like:

```
 if (array == NULL) return;
```

However, when I'm testing and it just returns, it becomes hard to know if my method succeeded at manipulating my array unless I check the array itself. Is it normal practice to add an assert in this case to ensure my condition for my own debugging purposes? I've heard that assert is not compiled for production code, so the assert would only be to help me, the programmer, test and debug. It seems kind of weird to have both if statement and an assert, but I don't see how the if statement could quickly allow me to know if my test method succeeded, and I don't see how assert could be a valid check for production code. So it seems like they're both needed?

Comment: What is the program supposed to do when running production if the test fails?

Comment: Uhmm I haven't thought that far yet, but unexpected behavior? Your program might do things you don't expect then? I guess my main question here is, is there anything wrong with doing a condition check to take care of production code as well as an assert to take care of debugging?

Comment: No nothing wrong with that. Though as an alternative to having the check twice (which would require changing it twice if needed) just have an `assert(0)` inside the `if` block. But there is no hard and fast rule with error checking. It depends alot on the context, the error handling style in the rest of the code base, what the caller of the function does in terms of error checking, whether the function is a library or an internal function, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the contract of your function is that it requires a valid pointer, the best possible behavior is to crash loudly when a null or otherwise invalid pointer is passed. You can't test the validity of a pointer in general, but in the case of null pointers, dereferencing them will crash on most systems anyway. An `assert` would be an appropriate way of documenting this and ensuring a crash (unless `NDEBUG` is defined) to aid in diagnosing usage errors.

Changing your function to return an error status is **not** a good idea. It complicates the interface and lets the contract violation go unnoticed until later (or not at all if the caller does not check the return value).

Comment: Just to add to this (correct) answer: A common way of seeing this in actual code is to see `assert(array && "Array argument ... was null!")`. The purpose is that this string literal will then appear in the assertion failure message, without changing the semantics of the assert. The `NDEBUG` thing is an implementation detail of the `assert` macro. In visual studio, if you do a "release" build, then `NDEBUG` is defined and this causes `assert` to be defined as an empty macro basically. If you don't want this behavior you can make a different macro based on the `abort` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic ideas.

Asserts are used to ensure some condition never occurs. The assert you've indicated ( assert( a != NULL ) ) would be used if it is not valid to call the function where a could be NULL.

As such, testing if ( a == NULL ) would make no sense. The assert indicates you consider this invalid. If you've significantly tested your code with the assert, you've "proven" (at least that's the idea) that you never call the function with a as NULL.

However, if by design, you intend that the function should gracefully ignore a when it is null, and do nothing, then a test is more appropriate. The assert would not be, because if you intend that the function is to be called with a null for some PURPOSE in mind, you don't need to be informed when that happens by having the debug mode trigger a breakpoint.

Which is to say, it makes little sense to combine the two.

A more "advanced" usage may check other values for validity. Say I have some class which processes bitmaps, and the bitmap is "owned" by the class, dynamically allocated and deleted appropriately. If I'm going to call any function in the class that performs operations on the bitmap, I must know it could never be NULL. Asserts would be appropriate to test the member pointer storing the bitmap data to be sure those functions aren't being called when the pointer IS null.

This is key to using asserts. You're attempting to prove the condition never occurs during debugging. That's the basic concept. As you're grappling with the possibility that it may be valid for such a value TO BE null, and still otherwise operate gracefully, you may find the combination of asserts AND tests to be reasonable. That is, you want to avoid crashes if other users of your code happen to make a call when the value IS null, but still not crash in production code if it happens to BE null.

Sometimes that's a performance hit you don't want to accept, and so you fire asserts so that consumers of your code know they're doing something you declare should never be done.